# BluetoothCrashResolver detects a crash on app launch

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, altbeacon, android-ibeacon

BluetoothCrashResolver detects a crash on app launch
the sequence of flow is as follows:

1.the device's bluetooth is off initially

2.the app is launched

3.the app first checks whether bluetooth is on

4.if not ON,app displays a popup to enable bluetooth

5.User allows bluetooth to be switched on

6.bluetoothresolver says "crash detected" as lastBluetoothTurningOnTime=01/01/1970;
lastBluetoothOffTime=01/01‌​/1970;
so the if statement inside "case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON" fails.

Let me know if any doubt understanding.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you add permissions in your manifest ??

Comment: yes.all permissions are there.I found out that manual toggling of bluetooth is also treated as crash.I am trying to find a way to disallow this behaviour as user may turn the BT on/off whenever he wants

Comment: when you run your application and the bluetooth is set ON, did it crash also ??

Comment: What is the symptom you are experiencing when you say "the if statement inside 'case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON' fails"?  Do you get a crash?  If so, can you please show the stack trace?

Comment: yes.it is a crash.if you go into the source code of BluetoothCrashResolver there are different case statements.The if statement inside "case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON" becomes true.hence the crash happens.